# LUA script error: Attempt to index a nil value (global 'nmap') stack traceback:

Tags: lua, nmap

I am trying to write code in LUA that will parse a SON file to retrieve the IP and pass it to NMAP and write a file of the IP's

I am receiving the following error message currently

lua discovery_n.lua
lua: discovery_n.lua:12: attempt to index a nil value (global 'nmap')
stack traceback:
discovery_n.lua:12: in main chunk
[C]: in ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local io = require('io')

-- Read JSON file
local file,err = io.open("discovery.json", "r")
if not file then
    error("Error: " .. err .. "\n" .. "JSON file not found, please make sure the file exists and the path is correct")
end
local json_data = file:read("*all")
file:close()

-- Parse JSON data
local data = nmap.registry.fromJSON(json_data)
if not data then
  error("error in parsing json")
end

-- Extract IP addresses
local host_list = data.Detail.host_list
if type(host_list) ~= "table" then
  error("host_list is not a table")
end

-- Iterate over host_list
for _, host in ipairs(host_list) do
    local ip_v4_address = host.host.ip_v4_address
    
    -- Run nmap command
    local nmap_command = "nmap -oX - " .. ip_v4_address
    local nmap_output = io.popen(nmap_command):read("*all")
    local output_table = Nmap.registry.import_raw(nmap_output)
    if not output_table then
      error("could not parse output of nmap command to a table")
    end

    -- Create xml string and write to file
    local output_xml = Nmap.registry.to_xml(output_table)
    local file = io.open(ip_v4_address .. ".xml", "w")
    if file then
        file:write(output_xml)
        file:close()
        print("nmap scan for "..ip_v4_address.." has been completed and exported to file "..ip_v4_address..".xml")
    else
        print("Error: ".. "Could not open or create the file for writing, check if the path is correct or you have enough permissions")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` is not a global, you have to require it.

```lua
require("nmap")
```

See https://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html